# How to pass props as a HTML tag to react element in dash plotly

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I am working on a dash project. I just learned [Create your own components](https://dash.plot.ly/react-for-python-developers) in dash.I created a simple component ie - **textarea**. Followiing is the code of component -

my_dash_component/mydashcomponent.react.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export default class mydashcomponent extends Component {

render(){
    const {id,setProps,value} = this.props;
    return(
    <div id={id}>
       <textarea cols="150" rows="45" value={value} onChange={e => {
                     if (setProps) {
                         setProps({
                            value: e.target.value
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            value: e.target.value
                        })
                    }
                }} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

mydashcomponent.defaultProps = {};

mydashcomponent.propTypes = {
   /**
   * The ID used to identify this component in Dash callbacks
   */
   id: PropTypes.string,

   /**
   * A label that will be printed when this component is rendered.
   */
   //label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

   /**
   * The value displayed in the input
   */
   value: PropTypes.string,

   /**
   * Dash-assigned callback that should be called whenever any of the
   * properties change
   */
   setProps: PropTypes.func
 };
```

I am using this component in usage.py

usage.py -

```
import my_dash_component
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div([

    my_dash_component.mydashcomponent(
      id='input',
      value='this is a text area',
   ),
html.Div(id='output')
])
```

My problem is when I pass the **value**(props) as a  plain text it works fine. But when i pass value as a html tag(ie. `value=<h2>This is a text area</h1>`) , it is giving invalid syntax error. 
How can i pass the value as a html tag?

Thank You.
Regards.

Comment: What do you mean with _as an html tag_? Do you want to show the html tags inside the textarea?
In that case, you should still pass a string: `value='<h2>This is a text area</h1>'`

Comment: No, i don't want to pass it as a string. I want to pass it as a html tag so that react can render it accordingly.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to insert (and interpret) HTML tags inside a _textarea_. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: There is a function , which returns the  html tag value and i need to pass it to this react component.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do

```
value=<h2>This is a text area</h1>
```

inside usage.py, this is invalid syntax.

Also in your proptypes you specify `value` needs to be a string and you're not passing in a string so it wouldn't work even if it was valid syntax.

```
/**
* The value displayed in the input
*/
value: PropTypes.string
```

Another problem is that as far as I know you can only have plain text inside a `textarea`.

What you can do instead is to create a `div` which has a `contentEditable` property set to `true`  in your custom component and pass `children` to this `div`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class mydashcomponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const {id, setProps, children} = this.props;
        return (
            <div id={id}>
                <div
                    contentEditable={true}
                    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                    cols="150"
                    rows="45"
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

mydashcomponent.defaultProps = {};

mydashcomponent.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    setProps: PropTypes.func,
};
```

`usage.py` can then look like this:

```
import mydashcomponent
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = mydashcomponent.mydashcomponent(html.H2("This is a text area"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

---

If you want to keep track of how the content of the div changes in your Dash app you could add an event listener and do something like this:

```
import React, {Component, createRef} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class mydashcomponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.editable = createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.editable.current.addEventListener(
            'input',
            (e) => {
                console.log(e.target);
                // prints something like <div contenteditable="true" cols="150" rows="45"><h2>This is a textarea</h2></div>
                // Do something with it like calling setProps with the text inside the h2 for the value property...
                this.props.setProps({value: e.target.children[0].textContent});
            },
            false
        );
    }
    render() {
        const {id, setProps, value} = this.props;
        return (
            <div id={id}>
                <div
                    contentEditable={true}
                    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                    ref={this.editable}
                    cols="150"
                    rows="45"
                >
                    <h2>{value}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

mydashcomponent.defaultProps = {};

mydashcomponent.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    setProps: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string,
};
```

```
import mydashcomponent
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        mydashcomponent.mydashcomponent(id="input", value="This is a text area"),
        html.Div(id="output"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("output", "children"), Input("input", "value"))
def func(value):
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```